# calculate occurrence using loop of an array

Tags: javascript

```
['a','a','b','a','s','g','h','t']
```

I have the above array, using a loop, how to know the number of occurrences of all the letters? For example `a` has appeared how many times?

The result expected is like:

```
a - 3
b - 5
s - ..
```

and so on..

Comment: The array is not valid. The elements should be wrapped in quotes. Here' my **answer:** `var arr = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 's', 'g', 'h', 't'];

var obj = {};
arr.forEach(function (v) {
    obj[v] = obj[v] ? obj[v] + 1 : 1;
});

console.log(obj);`

Comment: @morels Was that comment mean for me?

Comment: this means that the user cannot ask a question without providing a try, 2 rows. a proof that it is not a question for free code-dispencers...

Comment: @May Sun do you need also ordering the results?

Answer (score 1):

One approach it would be this one:

```
// Declare an array, in which you will store the distinct elements
// of your initial array.
var characters = [];

// Declare an array, in which you will store the times you find 
// each distinct element in your initial array.
// The counter in the 1st position is associated with the character 
// in the 1st position of characters.
var counters = [];

// Your initial array.
array = ['a','a','b','a','s','g','h','t'];

// Loop through the items of your array
for(var i=0, len=array.length; i<len; i++){

    var indexOfChar = characters.indexOf(array[i]);

    // If the current item is not included in the characters
    // push it there and push the corresponding counter to the
    // counters.
    if(indexOfChar===-1){
        characters.push(array[i]);
        counters.push(1);
    }else{ // The current item is found. So just increment the counter.
        counters[indexOfChar] += 1;
    }
}

// Print the results
for(var i=0, len=characters.length; i<len; i++){
    document.write(characters[i]+'-'+counters[i]+'<br/>');
}
```

```js
var characters = [];
var counters = [];
array = ['a','a','b','a','s','g','h','t'];

for(var i=0, len=array.length; i<len; i++){
    var indexOfChar = characters.indexOf(array[i]);
    if(indexOfChar===-1){
        characters.push(array[i]);
        counters.push(1);
    }else{ 
        counters[indexOfChar] += 1;
    }
}

for(var i=0, len=characters.length; i<len; i++){
   document.write(characters[i]+'-'+counters[i]+'<br/>');
}
```

> can this be done in forEach? this is hurting my eye

Of course it does, but it wasn't my first thought :(

```js
var array = ['a','a','b','a','s','g','h','t'];
var dict = {}; 
array.forEach(function (char) { dict[char] = dict[char] ? dict[char] + 1 : 1; }); 
for(var key in dict){
    if(dict.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        document.write(key+'-'+dict[key]+'<br/>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run this code? This will not work

Comment: No I didn't. Why not?

Comment: Okay, try to paste it in `console` and see errors

Comment: @Tushar after a correction I did in the declaration of array, worked.

Comment: can this be done in forEach? this is hurting my eye

Comment: @MaySun please see my update.

Comment: @Christos nice! but how to put it inside an array like [{'a':2,'b':4}] ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myarray = ['a','a','b','a','s','g','h','t'];
var countarray = [];

var Item = function(letter){
  this.letter = letter;
  this.count = 0;
}
for(var i=0;i<myarray.length;++i){
  countarray[myarray[i]] = countarray[myarray[i]] || new Item(myarray[i]);
  countarray[myarray].count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new object which contains number of element exist for particular array.

Please refer following example which create a object having all details about occurrence of every character-

```
elements_arr = ['a','a','b','a','s','g','h','t'];
//below statement creates object that will store details of character as a key and occurrence as a value .
occured_details = {};
for(i=0;i<elements_arr.length;i++)
{
    //if object having particular element the increase by one.
    if(occured_details.hasOwnProperty(elements_arr[i]))
    {
        occured_details[elements_arr[i]] += 1;
    }
    else//if object doesn't have character as a key then create new key and assign 1 occurrence to the key.
    {
       occured_details[elements_arr[i]] = 1;
    }

}
//
jQuery.each(occured_details, function(key, element) {
    alert('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + element);
});
```

To check example use this link-
http://jsfiddle.net/ks9tt953/

Comment: so have to loop twice?

Comment: Second loop was used to display values only.All calculation has done in first loop only

Comment: how to put it inside an array like [{'a':2,'b':4}]

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
   var freq = [];
   var ar = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 's', 'g', 'h', 't'];
    for (x = 0; x < ar.length; x++) {
        freq[ar[x]] = 0;
    }/*Initialize*/

    for (y = 0; y < ar.length; y++) {
        freq[ar[y]] += 1;
    }/*Operate*/

    for (i in freq) {
        console.log(i + "-" + freq[i]);
        /*This will display your desired output*/
    }/*Output*/
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: do you expect it to function?

Comment: @morels Yes, it works!

Comment: **1.** Use `var` for variable declarations **2.** Don't use `for..in` to loop over array **3.** _Three_ loops are not at all required

Comment: I can't see why not...besides this is only an example.